# Ver conexões ativas no servidor Firebird

Tags: firebird

Tenho um servidor Windows Server e nele temos instalado o Firebird Server Classic 2.5.
De que forma podemos verificar quantos clientes temos conectados ao servidor Firebird.

Obrigado.

Answer (score -1):

Tenta fazer esse select:

`SELECT * FROM MON$ATTACHMENTS`

Comment: eu tentei dessa forma, porém é falho, porque ficam conexões presas mesmo o cliente desconectando

Comment: Verifique as demais tabelas de monitoramento, para ficar conexão presa é possível que tenha transações presas e ai depende do controle transacional de sua aplicação.  mon$statements e mon$transactions